# TCPDF remote image loading problem

Tags: php, image, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

Im trying to load a remote image into a pdf generated by tcpdf however I can't seem to get it to work?

The rest of the pdf loads fine and it looks like to trying to retrieve the image however it just does print to the page?

The code I am using is:

```
$pdf->Image("http://media.domain.com/logo.jpg", 0, 0, 100, 150, 'JPEG', '', 'T', true, 72,'','','','','','','');
```

Any help on this would be a massive help,

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to set

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

in php.ini

It works for me

```
$pdf->Image('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=ls&chd=t:1366,1459,2534,2551,2589&chco=76A4FB&chls=2.0,0.0,0.0&chxt=x&chxl=0:|19|20|21|22|23&chs=600x150&chds=1366,2589', '', '', 100);
```

Update:

However, consider this recommendations regarding `allow_url_fopen`:
[Should I allow 'allow_url_fopen' in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127534/should-i-allow-allow-url-fopen-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been completely addressed on the latest TCPDF release. Just uprgade.
Check the TCPDF website at http://www.tcpdf.org and consult the official forum for further information.