# What would cause DOMDocument.load to fail loading XML from a URL that is accessible?

Tags: php, xml, dom

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
if ($doc->load('http://foo.com/bar.xml')) {
  // good
} else {
  // wtf happened?
}
```

I can `wget http://foo.com/bar.xml` from the location where the PHP code is running, so I know the URL is accessible.  I'm thinking it must be something other than an HTTP error.

I'm not sure what else could be causing the failure.  Maybe a parsing issue?  The XML appears to be valid (and passes W3C's validation test).  As far as I can tell from the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php), there's no way to determine *why* the load failure occurred.

Here's the XML:

```
 <response> 
  <version>8</version> 
  <minversion>1</minversion> 
  <url>api.asp?</url> 
 </response>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally narrowed it down to a [PHP configuration setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) called `allow_url_fopen`, which was set to `Off` on the server running the script.

I modified the `php.ini` file to enable this setting:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

And now `DOMDocument.load` can load XML from a remote URL.

**WARNING:** apparently there are some [security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127534/should-i-allow-allow-url-fopen-in-php) with keeping this setting on permanently.

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
    libxml_use_internal_errors ( true );
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc -> recover = true;
    $doc -> strictErrorChecking = false;
```

Comment: What's this do for me? (I'm not a PHP guy, this is a one-off thing I'm working on)

Comment: it simply suppresses errors and allows your code to continue in case of failure. to check what the exact problem is, append the following: `var_dump ( libxml_get_errors () );`

Comment: Oh, thanks! My code continues (it hits the `else` clause), but I need to know why.  Hopefully the `var_dump` will tell me what's wrong.

Comment: So, that just gave me "failed to
load external entity"; not quite as descriptive as I'd hoped. :)