# Access and manipulate XML file using DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I am trying to use DOMDocument to access an XML file, find data that matches a certain criteria, and then drop the node containing it if it does.  I then need to create a new XML file with the remaining data.

Below is the function I am using, with $current_balances being the full path to the XML file that i wish to use.  I am looking for a specific transaction date (which I will change to a variable one this is working), and if that date is found then I need to drop the node  that is associated with that date.

The porblem though is that I keep getting the following error, and I cannot figure out why -

> **Warning:** DOMDocument::loadXML()
>   [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag
>   expected, '<' not found in Entity,
>   line: 1

I hope that makes sense, and I hope someone is able to help.

Thanks.

```
function get_xml_data($current_balances = null){
 $doc = new DOMDOcument; 
 $doc->loadxml($current_balances);

 $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc); 
 foreach($xpath->query('//data[record/LastAccountsTransactionDate="2010-10-08"]') as $node) { 
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node); 
 } 
 echo $doc->savexml(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML loading seems to be the root of your problem, and determining which part of the XML file is triggering the error.

If you can confirm that a BOM in the file is not to blame, see this: [What would cause DOMDocument.load to fail loading XML from a URL that is accessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983786/what-would-cause-domdocument-load-to-fail-loading-xml-from-a-url-that-is-accessib/3983812#3983812)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have now discovered load and save, as opposed to loadxml and savexml, so I am now able to get in to the document and then save it as another.

The only bit I am not sure on now is how to cycle through each date, check that it is not older than 6 months (180 days) and remove it if it is.