# PHP Cannot Read External File

Tags: php, readfile, file-read

I am trying to read an external file, hosted on another server, but am having issues.

Here, I identify the variables:

```
$variable1 = "test";
$variable2 = "testing";
```

Here, I identify the URL to read:

```
$url = "http://test.com/page.php?v1=" . $variable1 . "&v2=" . $variable2;
```

Here, I read the external file:

```
$content = file($url);
$reading = $content[0];
echo $reading;
```

The odd thing is nothing comes out. I have tried entering the actual URL and it does work, however, when PHP tries to do it, it comes out blank.

I know it is not a fatal error as I tried just putting some regular text in there. So,there is something wrong that just is not reading the file correctly. Furthermore, I did make sure the reading server is no blocked by the server with the file on it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend wrapping your variables with `urlencode`, and `print_r` the content array to see if it starts with a blank line.  You might also consider `file_get_contents` depending on your end goal.

Comment: Make sure allow_url_fopen is set to true.  You can test this with ini_get()

Answer (score 0):

> Furthermore, I did make sure the reading server is no blocked by the server with the file on it.

How did you *make sure*?

---

First, ensure [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is `on` in `php.ini`.

If it is `on`, try setting a user agent. The remote file may expect a valid user agent.

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Your browser\'s user agent or whatever');
```

If it is `off`, try using the [cURL library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to request the remote file. You can use cURL to set the user agent too.

Comment: Allow_url_fopen is on. I tried setting the user agent with the agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9" Unfortunately, that did not work. :( Any other tips?

Comment: @Jacob Weird. The remote server may be expecting all of the typical *browser* headers. Did you try cURL? Are you able to make the remote URL public so I can test?

Answer (score 0):

You can try PHP's function **file_get_contents**

```
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: `file_get_contents()` will route through where `file()` does, so if `file()` doesn't work I doubt any of the native PHP file functions will.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read files and parse them from remote URLs you should make sure that the option ***allow_url_fopen*** is enabled in your php.ini configuration.

Please note that this option is disabled by default for security reasons.

http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

[Should I allow 'allow_url_fopen' in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127534/should-i-allow-allow-url-fopen-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a URL as a file name, allow_url_fopen must be enabled in php.ini. I would start there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching a website, and it starts with something like `<html>`, then echoing $content[0] will not show up when viewed from a browser.

Try:

```
echo htmlentities($content[0]);
```

Or:

```
print_r($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

`file()` loads data into an array. You then echo out only the first line of this document (`echo $reading[0]`). That first line is likely to be only an `<html>` tag or perhaps a doctype declaration.

If you're simply trying to echo out the full contents of the file, then do:

```
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

That fetches the specified URL and returns it as a single string - no line parsing, no array creation. Simply a plain string with the entire file in it.