# file_get_contents: Unable to find the wrapper “https” (XAMPP / Windows)

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying to deal with the TMDb API (The Movies Database).

I am getting the following error displayed again and again:

> file_get_contents: Unable to find the wrapper “https” (XAMPP / Windows)

For this code:

```
    $json = file_get_contents("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/5?api_key=XXXYYYZZZ&language=de-DE");
    $result = json_decode($json, true);
```

I have uncommented:

```
extension=openssl
```

and

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

on my php.ini an restartet XAMPP, but the problem persists.

What else can I do to solve this problem? :(

Comment: In which `php.ini` have you made the modifications? (You can run `php --ini` in the console to see the php.ini files on your machine and the one that is actually loaded. Make sure your modifications are done in the loaded one)

Comment: The configurations you need are `extension=php_openssl.dll` and 
`allow_url_include = On`.  But I will likely use `cURL` instead of `file_get_contents`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/127534/14066311

Comment: I have only one php.ini: x:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini

I made the changes mentioned by you, but it doesn't work. I will try curl instead.

Comment: I switched to MAMP. Everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents` is not good for HTTPS

Try with [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or some other HTTP libs like [here](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests) or [here](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive\xampp\

Comment: Whats about http libs ?